# Can not load data for newly adding drop down

Tags: jquery

I need to create dynamic drop down. I can load data for second drop down based on the value of first one. After that I need to add new rows of drop down as well. I can add new drop down rows. But I can not dynamically load value for newly added drop downs.

This is my jQuery to load data for second drop down:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#state").change(function() {
         alert('ok');
         var state = $("#state :selected").text();
        $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:8888/ajax/search_attendee.php",
                type:"post",
                data:'state='+ state,
                dataType: "html",
                success:function(data){
                $("#trainer").html(data);
                }
            });

     });

    });
</script>
```

This is jQuery to load new rows. I can add rows by this function. But I can not load data for my second drop down. Can anybody help me to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
     var addDiv = $('#addinput');
     var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

     $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
      $('<p>'+
                   '<table id="datatable"><tr><td width="220"></td><td>'+
                    '<select name="state_' + i +'" id="state">'+
                    '<option value="0">Select State</option>'+
                    '<option value="1">QLD</option>'+
                    '<option value="2">NSW</option>'+
                    '<option value="3">VIC</option>'+
                    '<option value="4">WA</option>'+
                    '<option value="5">ACT</option>'+
                    '<option value="6">NT</option>'+
                    '<option value="7">SA</option>'+
                    '<option value="8">TAS</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                    '<select name="trainer_' + i +'" id="trainer"><option>Select Trainer</option></select>'+
                    '<a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a></td></tr></table></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
         i++;


 });

    $('#remNew').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
       }

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to delegate your event to closest static parent usign `on` for dynamically added element. which is `#state` in your case

```
    $(document).on('change','#state',function() {
        alert('ok');
        var state = $("#state :selected").text();
       .....
```

you might also need to change your `live()` to `on()` if you are using latest jquery version i.e. 1.6+
since live is deprecated

```
  $(document).on('click','#addNew',function() {
     ....


  $(document).on('click','#remNew', function() { 
     ...
```

this works however, delegating your dynamic element to closest static element which is present in the document at the time of insertion is better than to use the document itself performance wise.

Comment: I changed according to your answer.but still i can  load data for second drop down only in first row.After i added new rows with drop down i can not load data for second drop down.

Comment: make sure your id is unique for each elements.. sounds like you have same id for multiple elements...can u create a fiddle ?